# Spring MVC mapping query parameters instead of URI templates values with @PathVariable

Tags: spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAccount(@PathVariable String id)
        throws ProfileNotFoundException {
   System.out.println(id);
   return null;
}
```

.../account/12345 results in null

.../account/test?id=12345 '12345' results in 12345

Not sure how to fix this but I'd like the first link to work instead of the second.  Here is my webmvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd                 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd                 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.twheys.lexika.web.**"
        use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"
            type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: that should work, the second reference with test in the url definitely should not work

Comment: Right, but that's what's happening. Not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify it as `@PathVariable("id")` - without that the HandlerMethodArgumentResolver responsible for resolving the value of the argument tries to figure out the parameter value by parameter name, the parameter name (id) gets lost during compilation though(unless debug symbols are on during compilation, which typically it is not).

Comment: Okay, you can try debugging this issue - a breakpoint in PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver should show what could be going wrong, your path looks perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authors/{authorId}")
public ModelAndView getAuthorById(@PathVariable String authorId) {
    Author author = bookService.getAuthorById(authorId);
    ModelAndView mav = 
        new ModelAndView("bookXmlView", BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "author", author);
    return mav;
}
```

Above Code works fine for me. Kindly use in similar manner.